# How to change RecordType name as different in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, record-type

i have 10 RecordTypes, am showing that RecordType Names in page.  In vf page i am showing the RecordType names using this line.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!wart.article.RecordType.Name}"/></div>
```

'Holiday' is one RecordType name. If the RecordType name is 'Holiday', i need to show the name 'Closing Timings'. I don't want to change RecordType Name because that is used in so many places. Only one page i need to change 'Closing Timings' instead of 'Holiday'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do in different ways..

1.using conditional expressions in the VF page component tag like below

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(wart.article.RecordType.Name == 'Holiday','Closing Timings',wart.article.RecordType.Name)}"/>
```

or

2.in the apex controller used in the VF page

or

3.using javascript to replace the value client side